# Await http request done then continue the loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I do not know how to do this. I am starting to learn javascript.
Can anybody help me? Here is my code:

```
let url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=driveid";
   while(true) {
      let check = false;
      console.log(url);
      const request = https.get(url, (response) => {
         if(typeof response.headers['Content-Disposition'] !== "undefined") {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream("a3.mp4");
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
               file.write(chunk);
            }).on('end', async () => {
               file.end();
               check = true;
            })
         } else {
            let str = "";
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
               str += chunk;
            }).on('end', () => {
               url = get_confirm_download_url(str);
               if(!url) {
                  console.log("Can\"t find download link");
                  check = true;
               }
            })
         }
      });
      if(check) break;
   }
```

I really need your help

Comment: What do you want to achive? Add a description of your problem in order to obtain accurately help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I have the right end of the stick here, but I've made some assumptions looking at your code. Try this:

```js
let url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=driveid'
let check = true // Tell the app we're okay to check

while (check) {
  check = false // Set to false while the app is checking
  console.log(url)
  https.get(url, (response) => {
    if (typeof response.headers['Content-Disposition'] !== 'undefined') {
      const file = fs.createWriteStream('a3.mp4')
      response
        .on('data', (chunk) => {
          file.write(chunk)
        })
        .on('end', async () => {
          file.end()
          check = true // Done – tell the app it's safe to check again
        })
    } else {
      let str = ''
      response
        .on('data', (chunk) => {
          str += chunk
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          url = get_confirm_download_url(str)
          if (!url) {
            console.log('Can"t find download link')
            check = true // Done – tell the app it's safe to check again
          }
        })
    }
  })
  // No need for the break
}

There are definitely better ways of doing this - but it seems to me like this is what you were intending to do.
```